# Java Clock simulation, don't know how to proceed with do...while

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

I was asked in school to do a clock simulation in java, where the user sets an initial time (example: 12:34:56) and an end time that must be greater than the initial time (ex: 13:34:56) the program will only print every single change in the clock until the end time is reached, so far I have done all of this: (ignore Spanish words)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Examen {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner t= new Scanner (System.in);
    int inhora, inmin, inseg, finhora, finmin, finseg;
    do
    {
    System.out.println("Ingresa una hora de inicio:");
    inhora=t.nextInt();
    if (inhora <0 || inhora>=24)
        System.out.println("Hora incorrecta");
    }
    while (inhora <0 || inhora>=24);

    do
    {
    System.out.println("Ingresa el minuto de inicio:");
    inmin=t.nextInt();
    if (inmin <0 || inmin>=60)
        System.out.println("Minuto incorrecto");
    }
    while (inmin <0 || inmin>=60);

    do
    {
    System.out.println("Ingresa el segundo de inicio:");
    inseg=t.nextInt();
    if (inseg <0 || inseg>=60)
        System.out.println("Segundo incorrecto");
    }
    while (inseg <0 || inseg>=60);

    System.out.println("Hora de inicio ingresada: "+inhora+":"+inmin+":"+inseg);

     do
    {
    System.out.println("Ingresa una hora de finalización:");
    finhora=t.nextInt();
    if (finhora <0 || finhora>=24)
        System.out.println("Hora incorrecta");
    if (finhora<inhora)
            System.out.println("La hora final tiene que ser mayor que la inicial");
    }
    while (finhora <0 || finhora>=24);

    do
    {
    System.out.println("Ingresa el minuto de finalización:");
    finmin=t.nextInt();
    if (finmin <0 || finmin>=60)
        System.out.println("Minuto incorrecto");
    }
    while (finmin <0 || finmin>=60);

    do
    {
    System.out.println("Ingresa el segundo de finalización:");
    finseg=t.nextInt();
    if (finseg <0 || finseg>=60)
        System.out.println("Segundo incorrecto");
    }
    while (finseg <0 || finseg>=60);

    System.out.println("Hora final ingresada: "+finhora+":"+finmin+":"+finseg);

    do
    {
        System.out.println(inhora+":"+inmin+":"+inseg);             

            inseg++;
        if (inseg>59)
        {
            inseg=0;
            inmin++;
        }
        if (inmin>59)
        {
            inmin=0;
            inhora++;
        }

        if (inhora>23)
        {
            inhora=0;
        }


    } while (inhora!=finhora);
}
}
```

My problem is at the final "while" I don't know which condition should I put in there in order to do the task I am aiming for, with this "while (inhora!=finhora);" all I get is (for example: initial time 0:0:0 end time 23:59:59) all the changes in the clock until 22:59:59

Comment: I, personally, would convert both times to their lowest common denominator, maybe seconds, which would make it easier to increment, but that's me

Comment: @MadProgrammer you and anyone who has tried to implement this. It's the "correct" way.

Comment: Convert everything into total seconds since 0:0:0 and proceed calculations in int format.

Comment: java.util.Calendar is your friend. It might be called Calendar, but it works for time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're breaking out of the `do-while` loop too early and printing the values of the time before they get incremented. Changing the loop into this would fix the problem:

```
do {
    inseg++;

    // clipped out the min/hour incrementing code

    System.out.println(inhora+":"+inmin+":"+inseg);

} while (inhora < finhora || inmin < finmin || inseg < finseg);
```

Note that because of short-circuiting we need to `OR` together the evaluation of hours, minutes and seconds in this specific order. This means that `inmin < finmin` only gets evaluated when `inhora < finhora` is `false`, etc.

Comment: Yes! thank you very much, all of you. I know this was a super newbie thing to ask, but you saved me, and I will try to never make that mistake again.